# How to find the load context of a type

Tags: .net, mef

I might be having problems with the load context when loading types dynamically (I'm using MEF). So I want to print out what context a certain type/object was loaded in (Load, LoadFrom, or LoadNeither), but can't seem to find the property on Type/Assembly/Module/whatever that gives that information.